# return and edit of multiple variables [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, game-engine, multiple-value

i have a problem in my first Game engine so please help me :(

*There is two part in the first one i will explain the problem and in the second one i will explain my questions .*

**Part I :**

> i have an array (named "World") of object class
>
> ```
> public Object World[] = new Object[500];
> ```
>
> the object have many properties (name,x,y,animation,length,width ....)
>
> i want to make condition of collession for example
>
> ```
> if( Function_to_detect_collessions("object1_name","object2_name") ){
> object2.Animation = "new value" ;
> }
> ```
>
> and with these lines you will understand me :
>
> 1- many object can get the same name
>
> 2- if more than one collession happened with more than two objects
>   with the same names (object1_name and object2_name) then the
>   modification for the object2.animation will be on all the touched
>   objects
>
> ```
> example :
> if( collesion("ball","ground") ){
> ball.movement = stop;
> }
> //Now imagine that there is two objects (two Balls) on the ground
> ```

**Part II :**

> i think that you understand me what i mean and now i will explain my
>   question.   questions :
>
> 1- if i can detect all the collessions how to make the modification on
>   all the objects with one line like
>
> ```
> object2.prop = "something"
> ```
>
> 2- is it possible in java to make modification on an object and with
>   some functions make the same modification on more than one object
>   automatically .

### -----------------------------------------------------

I'm **Sorry** for my bad English but i tried to use all the words in my mind to explain the problem and i wish i did (**any answer could help me even with a part of a solution so please help**)

Comment: Doing these things is usually but doing it fast is really hard. Just remember that if you can code it in one line it does not mean that it will run fast. Very often using more lines to do something will make it faster.

Comment: I know that my engine will not be fast but i don't want to make it complicated because this is my first Engine , maybe in the next version i will try to find a solution for this kind of problems :) thank you anyway

Comment: You need to look at the logic of what you are trying to do and then find the best/fastest solution to architect the use case. If you have 500 objects which use 500 unique variables to store the velocity of each object there is no alternative other than looping over 500 variables and updating each of them. An optimization would be to keep a list of only moving objects e.g. but stationary objects can also collide with moving ones! If you have collection of objects (e.g. Arraylist) you could do this in one line : for (gameObject obj: allObects)   obj.prop = "something";

Comment: yeah that's it , could you please explain for me what you have said [[ for (gameObject obj: allObects) obj.prop = "something";  ]] or give me a link for more explication please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Java collections like this:

```
public ArrayList<Object> World= new ArrayList<>();

for (int i =0; i<500; i++)
  World.add(new Object(i));

// Update all objects
for (Object myObject : World) myObject.prop = "Something";
```

EDIT:

As per your subsequent question. If you need to go only over a particular list you can do this:

```
public ArrayList<Object> MoversAndShakers = new ArrayList<>();

MoversAndShakers.add(World.get(3));
MoversAndShakers.add(World.get(5));
MoversAndShakers.add(World.get(9));

// Update all MoversAndShakers
for (Object myObject : MoversAndShakers) myObject.prop = "Something";
```

Or even better you could encapsulate that in a function to detect collisions (You may want to look at this question on how to do that [Simple and fast collision algorithm in java for non-axis aligned boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594857/collision-algorithm-in-java-for-squares)) :

```
public ArrayList<Object> MoversAndShakers = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object>  getMovingObjects(ArrayList<Object> World)
{
  ArrayList<Object> MoversAndShakers = new ArrayList<>();

  for(Object currentObj : World)
  {
     if (currentObj.velocity > 0)
          MoversAndShakers.add(currentObj);
  }
  return MoversAndShakers;
}
```

And then above reduces to this

```
// Update all moving objects
for (Object myObject : getMovingObjects(World)) 
   myObject.prop = "Something";
```

Comment: this what i mean thank you :) :) , but i do not want to change prop = "somthing" of all the object i need it just for some object for example Number1,5,7 and 8 is there a solution ??

Comment: You can either keep a list of the objects to change, and replace "World" with "ObjectsToChange" and instead of adding all 500 you can add only the ones you want to change. Remember this is always pointers to the objects so it does not make copies.

Alternatively you can add a condition to the for-loop.

Comment: The Last question --> does **public ArrayList<Object> World= new ArrayList<>();** mean that World is a pointer if not how to make the declaration of the pointer ? and thank you

Comment: In java all objects (except for primitives) are always pointers (also sometimes called references).

Comment: You could make 500 of them like this : public Object World[] = new Object[500]; You are already doing this in your code ...

Comment: Thank you , you helped me with all my problems(Bad English ,Stupid programming ...) :) :) Thank you

Comment: BTW. I just saw this question which you may also want to take a look at :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594857/collision-algorithm-in-java-for-squares