# Simple and fast collision algorithm in java for non-axis aligned boxes

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

I'm making a program that needs to detect the collision between 2 non-axis aligned boxes. My program only needs an indication if 2 non-axis aligned boxes are colliding. I would like to have the most simple and efficient algorithm possible.

Here I visualized the problem.
[image: Problem]

So as you can see squares 1,2 and 3 would return true because they collided with the green squares.
4 would return false because it isn't colliding.

I do have all the boxes of both colors in separate array lists.

Does anybody know a library or algorithm for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you representing your game world?

Comment: Do your squares (rectangles) and border area have properties that could be used to determine location?

Comment: @ThanePlummer yes I do know the width, heigh,t x-,and y-position.

Comment: @VivinPaliath not sure what you mean but it's just the  orthographic camera from libgdx I guess, don't really know what you mean :/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Area class in the java.awt.geom package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html

Comment: Shoudldn't I rather use the Shape class?

Comment: Shape is an interface that's implemented by the Area class. So they're very similar, but you actually instantiate objects of the Area class.

Comment: This would take polynomial time (`O(n^2)`) because he would have to compare each instance with every other one.

Comment: I've used R-Tree to optimize these kind of searches, so you could look for a geometric library that includes R-Tree implementation. I've used R-Trees in the new versions of the boost library, but that's C++ not Java.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly-used approach involves [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). There's a good write-up and tutorial [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374), which explains how to use quadtrees to perform collision detection in 2D space.

The general idea is that your game area will keep being partitioned by four as your add objects. Each partition is called a node and each node will maintain a reference to objects that exist in the corresponding partition. Objects are placed into nodes based on where they are in the 2D space. If a node does not fit cleanly into a partition, it is inserted into the parent node. Using this method, you don't have to perform an expensive check against every other object in your 2D space, because you can be sure that objects in different nodes (at the same level; i.e., sibling nodes) will not collide. So you only have to perform your collision detection on a small subset of objects.

Note that this just tells you which objects are occupying a certain area; it's a more efficient way to hone in on objects that are *likely* to be colliding. After that you have to check if the objects are actually colliding. There is another write-up [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-with-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169) that goes over various techniques to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "easy" your game really is, how many shapes you'd have to check for (I'm thinking efficiency here), but if you have your different color shapes in different lists, a kind of brute force iteration may work for you. Not a clue if it would be efficient enough for you. I use box2D to tell me the collisions, but sounds like that may be overkill for you.

The brute force method I'm thinking of would be to utilize libgdx's Intersector class (check out the API, it has lots of methods). Iterate through your rectangles comparing to the others. Something like IntersectRectangles() gives you a boolean if two rectangles overlap (ie: collide).

This may be too inefficient/hacky, and a physics library may be too much. So one of the other answers provided may be the sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two algorithms/data-structures you need to consider for this problem:

- A spatial data-structure to store your rotated quads, to efficiently determine which pairs of quads need to be tested against each other. Other answers have already addressed this. If the number of quads is small enough then you can just test all the red quads against all the green quads, which is O(m * n).
- An algorithm to perform the actual test of one rotated quad against another. One of the simplest is the [Separating Axis Theorem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection).

The basic idea behind the SAT is that if you can find at least one line where all the points of one convex object are on one side of it, and all the points of the other are on the other side, then the two are not colliding. The potential lines that you need to test are just the edges of both of the objects.

To implement it you need to implement a point-line test to tell you which side of an edge a point is on. This is done by calculating the normal to the edge, and then calculating the dot product of the edge normal and a vector from a point on the edge to the point you are testing. The sign of the dot product tells you which side the point is on (positive means the outside the edge, for an outward pointing normal). Whether you count zero (on the line) as outside or inside depends on whether you want objects that are just touching but not penetrating to count as a collision, if you do then the dot product must be greater than zero to count as outside.

For example if the points on objects are in clockwise order, and edgeA and edgeB are the two points of an edge on one object, and pointC is a point on the other object, the test is done like this (not using function calls, to show the math):

```
boolean isOutsideEdge(PointF edgeA, PointF edgeB, PointF pointC)
{
    float normalX = edgeA.Y - edgeB.y;
    float normalY = edgeB.X - edgeA.x;
    float vectorX = pointC.x - edgeA.x;
    float vectorY = pointC.y - edgeA.y;
    return (normalX * vectorX) + (normalY * vectorY) > 0.0f;
}
```

Then the algorithm is:

- For each edge on quad A, if all the corner points on quad B are on the outward facing side of the edge, then A and B are not colliding, stop processing and return false.
- For each edge on quad B, if all the corner points on quad A are on the outward facing side of the edge, then A and B are not colliding, stop processing and return false.
- If all those tests have been performed and none have returned false, then A and B are colliding, so return true.

The SAT can be generalized to arbitrary convex polygons.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to go with box2d in the end. This was the best solution because of the diffrent mask-qualifiers, the objects didn't collide but it could be easily checked wether they should be colliding.

I had to make my own contactlistener that overrides the default contactlistener. Here I could do anything if any 2 objects collided.

Thanks everyone for the help.